# How to open web browser with UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, safari, uiwebview

Hey guys,
On my Xcode project, I am trying to open a web browser at the click of one of my buttons, but here's what I'm really trying to do. First of all, I am opening a web browser using this example code:

```
NSURL *fanPageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/210227459693"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: fanPageURL]) {
    NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/pages/Blackout-Labs/210227459693"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: webURL];
}
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Now this code works properly, but the problem is that it's closing my application and opens the link in the Safari application, which is not what I want. I went the other way around by creating another view (after click the button), then inserted a UIWebView using Interface Builder, but it still didn't work. So I was hoping someone can help me out how to open this link within my app instead of closing my app and opening the link in the Safari app, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [`SVWebViewController`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController). It's a ready made `UIViewController` subclass with a `UIWebView` in it and all you need to do to show it is

```
SVWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:@"http://google.com"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

There is also a modal version, see the [Usage Section](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController#usage).

Comment: wow thanks, so about this SVWebViewController, do I have to create it or just drag the folder into my project, then code in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a `UIViewController` subclass that has `UIWebView` as a subview, and show that when the button in tapped.